# Edit Recent Contacts in Text History in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to edit or delete the recent contacts in the text history on an iPhone? The problem is that when you start to enter a name (that is deleted on the phone) it will appear in the text message address history. There are various "solutions" on the Internet that don't work, so I thought that there may be a way to do this with Objective-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct API into the Text messaging framework unfortunately.

You could try using ABAddressBookRemoveRecord.
Failing that, if there is a way it would be documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Thanks Alex. I'll try this. Apple needs to provide a developer mode for their phones like Windows Phone 8 and WebOS does to give developers full access to it. :)